# Reinstall Windows 10 using ISO onto new SSD without losing activation status

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

I bought my laptop that comes pre-install Windows 10 Home Single Language (activated).

However I wish to reinstall the my current Windows onto a upgraded SSD drive.

And I don't wish to lose my activation after reinstall.

Therefore I don't want to download any ISO file comes from outside sources

I wish I can create my own ISO from my current installed Windows OS.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Can I use the **Backup and Restore (Windows7)** comes from Control Panel to create this?

Will it lose my activation?

Can it reinstall onto different drive? (I remembered I did once before with a USB flash drive that only run UEFI menu to restore my Windows but without option to install onto different drive)

Comment: Try cloning your drive instead of reinstaliing Windows.

Comment: after clone would it auto show selection of 2 OS to boot during startup?

Comment: No, it will boot from the drive you choose, not from the OS, because they're the same.

Comment: do I need to wipe my old drive?

Comment: You *don't* need to wipe your old drive, but you can do it if you want to.

Comment: but then it will notice about 2 bootable drives right? how could it automatically boot from new one

Comment: You have to change the boot order from your BIOS.

Comment: "I  wish I can create my own ISO from my current installed Windows OS." - This is not required.  It is a waste of time.  Download the current Windows 10 Single Language directly from Microsoft.  Install Windows 10 Single Language.  You must install the exact same language you already have installed.  However, All editions of Windows 10 provide a digital entitlement.

Comment: "Can I use the Backup and Restore (Windows7) comes from Control Panel to create this?" - No

Answer (score 2):

If your computer has UEFI BIOS then your licence key is installed on your BIOS, you only need to download the original Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Also many manufacturers allow download their OEM ISO from their support pages (i.e. [Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/19/category/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/Operating-Systems/windows-operating-systems/windows-10-support?lwp=rt))

If you download and install the same ISO version that came pre-installed on your computer it will automatically reactivate with Microsoft, I have done it several times when i have to replace dead hard drives or reformat computers

Comment: because I'm still afraid it will not prompt for which drive to install since this is OEM customized installer compared to Original Windows ISO

Comment: My laptop is Lenovo, and yes, I actually made one as USB flash drive

Comment: "If your computer has UEFI BIOS then your license key is installed on your BIOS" - Why does everyone say this?  The Windows 10 key is NOT store in the BIOS.  It's stored in the ACPI table.  **While related to one another there is a huge difference.**

Comment: "since this is OEM customized installer compared to Original Windows ISO" - No; No it isn't.  Lenovo uses the standard Windows 10 Single Language ISO.